# wkhtmltopdf not printing ℃ in pdf

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm converting html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf. wkhtmltopdf not printing ℃ (&#x2103) in pdf instead it prints dodgy character.  Html file displaying ℃ but missing in pdf. I have got http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" in html file. Please suggest any ideas.

Comment: Which font are you using? Why not use two separate entities instead: `&deg;` and `C`. I'm pretty sure `°C` will work in every case.

Comment: Thanks emix for reply. I'm using font: arial. This working fine in dev machine but failed in test and production env.